# Spring MVC / Security No-Static Role Based Authentication

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security, spring-annotations

I implemented spring-mvc based java application via no-xml. How to do set rol based authentication for each controller method?

I don't want to static role name `facultyMember` like following code:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('facultyMember')")
public Newsletter getFacultyNews() { }
```

Comment: how do you wan't to authorize then?

Comment: I want to change authorize in runtime. For example : x person authorized controller method and after i will change to not authorized this method.

Comment: A role is nothing more than a permission (albeit the name can be misleading). A role is basically nothing more then a collection of permissions. Why would you want to change the permission one needs to have to access a part of your application? That should be fairly static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it seems odd that the permission to access a service is to be made dynamic, you can try and use an external properties file:

In your application context:

```
<bean id="myProp" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="locations">
         <list>
              <value>file:///pathToExternalPropertyFile/myProp.properties</value>
           </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Then in your controller class:

```
@Value("#{myProp['dynamicRole']}")
private String dynamicRole;

@PreAuthorize("hasRole('"+dynamicRole +"')")
public Newsletter getFacultyNews() { }
```

Comment: The problem is that when we decide to make a change—for example, maybe teaching assistants should be allowed to read the faculty newsletters too—we have to go into the code to make a change:  `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('facultyMember') or hasRole('teachingAssistant')")
public Newsletter getFacultyNews() { ... }` Its caused of new release. I dont want to do this.

Comment: Check my edited answer that can be controlled by an external file